# Is there a way to update a calculation view through a query on SAP HANA?

Tags: sql, xml, hana

I'm working on updating hundreds of calculation views on SAP HANA.
I should update (for every calculation view) the last aggregation/projection columns : `Keep flag = True`.

There's a way, by updating XML Code of every calculation view file Like below:

```
<attribute id="EQUNR" order="3" attributeHierarchyActive="false" 
           displayAttribute="false" keepFlag="true">
  <descriptions defaultDescription="EQUNR"/>
```

But, my question is, is there a way to update this `Keep Flag` through a query on SQL Console ?

if not, is there any other method you suggest guys ?

Every idea matters, Thank you folks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this via SQL.

Although you may be able to author a regex expression that matches some of the target XML tags, there’s no way of correctly updating the repository tables storing the source XML (if you’re using the HANA classic repository).
For HANA 2 HDI files no DB command can change the source code as these are not stored in the database.

Beyond this technical issue, it’s probably not a good idea to apply a flag **that changes query semantics** as a batch update.